# Ubuntu error on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10, wubi

I installed **Ubuntu** version **12.10** using **Wubi** on my **lenovo** laptop. When I choose to boot as Ubuntu, a black screen appeared and Ubuntu isn't starting. A few days earlier, I installed it on my **hp** laptop but this problem didn't appear. What's wrong?

Comment: So is there an actual error or does your system just fail to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Actually, I don't know why it didn't start. My laptop is new so I don't think this problem is caused by the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell from little information you gave, but most likely the cause is a issue with some unsupported hardware: why not try a more recent release?